# Validación de formulario javaScript

Tags: javascript, html, jquery, formularios

He creado una web con varios formularios. Les incluí un botón para que tengan que aceptar los términos y hasta que no se hace check no se puede enviar. Pero aun así recibo muchísimo spam, entonces quiero validar que los campos no vayan vacíos y que alguna validación más.

Pongo un formulario super sencillo para suscribirse a una Newsletter, para no llenar esto mucho.

Código del formulario:

```
       <form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="news" method="post" >
          <div class="form-group">
            <i class="far fa-envelope form-control-email"></i>
            <input type="email" class="form-control myInput" name="email" id="email" placeholder="Tu email...">
          </div>
          <div class="" id="mensajeNEWS">
            <input name="chec" class="chzxc" type="checkbox" id="chec" onchange="comprobarNews(this);" style="display:inline-block;">
            <label class="labTerm" style="display:inline;">He leído y acepto la <a href="privacidad-y-condiciones.php" title="Privacidad y Condiciones">Privacidad y Condiciones</a></label>
          </div>
          <button type="submit" id="llamada229" class="btn btn-primary btnNews" disabled>Suscribete</button>
        </form>
```

Función Javascript para la respuesta del envio.

```
$(function(){
     $("#news").on("submit", function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
         var f = $(this);
         var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("news"));
         formData.append("dato", "valor");

         $.ajax({
             url: "respuestas/respuesta-news.php",
             type: "post",
             dataType: "html",
             data: formData,
             cache: false,
             contentType: false,
             processData: false,

              beforeSend: function(){
               $("#mensajeNEWS").html("<div class='ui active inline loader myLoader' style='margin-bottom:1%;'></div>")
               },
              success: function (resultado){
               setTimeout(function(){
                 $("#mensajeNEWS").html(resultado);
               }, 1300);
             }
           });
               setTimeout(function () {
                 location.reload();
               }, 5000); //will call the function after 2 secs
        });
     });
```

Para comprobar si el check esta clicado y así se activa el botón.

```
function comprobarNews(obj)
    {
      if (obj.checked)
       document.getElementById('llamada229').disabled = false;
      else
       document.getElementById('llamada229').disabled = true;
    }
```

Todo esto funciona, pero como hago para validar los campos??? Saludos

Comment: Si solamente quieres evitar que vayan vacíos con ponerle a los `<input>` el atributo `required` te valdría. Ejemplo: `<input type="text" required>`.

Comment: Hola y gracias por tu respuesta, pero `required` no funciona en todos los navegadores si no recuerdo mal no?

Comment: 100% compatible con todos los navegadores, por lo que MDN dice: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Attributes/required

Comment: No está claro a que te refieres con "validar los campos". ¿Te refieres a que sean obligatorios?

Comment: Sabes aunque coloques un `jquery validate` o un `required`, tu problema es otro. Te aconsejo que estudies `CAPTCHA`

Comment: Gracias a todos por vuestros mensajes, de momento voy a realizar la opción de la respuesta que me dan más abajo. Si me gustaria estudiar lo del `captcha`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

podrias hacer un if antes de enviar la consulta.

```
    $(function(){
     $("#news").on("submit", function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
         var f = $(this);
         var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("news"));
         formData.append("dato", "valor");

         //una ves se presione el boton y antes de enviar por ajax
         if ($("#email").val().trim() != '') {
          $.ajax({
             url: "respuestas/respuesta-news.php",
             type: "post",
             dataType: "html",
             data: formData,
             cache: false,
             contentType: false,
             processData: false,

              beforeSend: function(){
               $("#mensajeNEWS").html("<div class='ui active inline loader myLoader' style='margin-bottom:1%;'></div>")
               },
              success: function (resultado){
               setTimeout(function(){
                 $("#mensajeNEWS").html(resultado);
               }, 1300);
             }
           });
            setTimeout(function () {
                 location.reload();
               }, 5000); //will call the function after 2 secs
         }else{
          alert('email vacio');
         }

        });
     });

function comprobarNews(obj)
    {
      if (obj.checked)
       document.getElementById('llamada229').disabled = false;
      else
       document.getElementById('llamada229').disabled = true;
    }
```

Si de paso, necesitas validar mas campos (que es lo mas seguro) debes agregar otro if dentro. Por ejemplo:

```
$(function(){
     $("#news").on("submit", function(e){
         e.preventDefault();
         var f = $(this);
         var formData = new FormData(document.getElementById("news"));
         formData.append("dato", "valor");

         //una ves se presione el boton y antes de enviar por ajax
         if ($("#nombre").val().trim() != '') {
            if ($("#email").val().trim() != '') {
              //aqui tu codigo si todo es correcto
            }else{
              alert('email vacio');
            }
         }else{
          alert('nombre vacio');
         }

        });
     });
```

Solo debes usar $("#input").val() dentro de el if reemplazando #input por el ID de tu input. Otra cosa importante también es agregar después de val() la opción .trim() que automáticamente elimina los espacios en blanco. Saludos.

Comment: Muchas gracias por la solución!! ;)

Comment: Te recomendaría que vieras el tema de captaba como dicen mas arriba. Puedes usar el de google, es muy fácil de integrar y solo debes integrar un código javascript, por ende no es necesario modificar casi nada de tu código. Busca la documentación, está todo en español y fácil de entender. Suerte.